# Boost version at least 1.56 on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, boost, driver

I need to build MongoDB C++ Driver. It needs Boost version at least 1.56, while my current Boost version is default Boost 1.54 (libboost-all-dev) on Ubuntu Trusty.

I can't find suitable PPAs. Is it possible to install Boost 1.56 on Ubuntu Trusty? or even better Boost 1.62?

Comment: Are you trying to build the legacy C++ driver, or the new mongocxx driver, which requires C++11?

Comment: mongocxx driver, i need to build from source as i can't install it with apt-get. I really wonder why mongodb inc is not making it ready and easy with apt-get

Comment: We are working on it, but it takes time, and there are other priorities. In any event, it wouldn't help you here, because we would still require the boost version that we require, meaning that it wouldn't be able to be packaged for that distro. That said, is there a particular reason you require the boost polyfill, as opposed to using MNMLSTC, which is the default?

Comment: @acm, i switched to MNMLSTC/core polyfill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost 1.56 is required for Boost polyfill, however, MongoDB C++ Driver can just be compiled using default *MNMLSTC/core* polyfill.

At Step 4 in https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/. Use default polyfill insteaed of Boost polyfill.

MNMLSTC/core polyfill:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Boost polyfill:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```